# How do I set up Google Talk in Pidgin?

Tags: pidgin, google-talk

When I try setting up Google Talk in Pidgin. I get the message:

> Unable to Connect

**EDIT:**

(I have it working in Digsby fine)

Here is my setup:

[image]
[image: Advanced Tab]

Comment: I checked my configuration - it looks the same, but in the `connect server` box it's just blank, which appears to be the default setting for Google Talk. Perhaps try taking that out and see if it works?

Comment: Having the same problem. Did you ever find the answer?

Comment: How do you get it to work if you have a Google account but don't have a Gmail account?

Comment: i follow your guide religously but i get Not Authorized. Help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set up Google Talk/Hangout in Pidgin?](https://superuser.com/questions/973514/how-do-i-set-up-google-talk-hangout-in-pidgin)

Answer (score 20):

Google created the new **Google Hangout**, that replaces also Google Talk, and seems that **XMPP support has been removed**.

But there's a partial solution: [enable access to Gmail from "less secure apps"](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) and Pidgin will connect to it.

Comment: This fixed the Not Authorized error im getting. Why nobody rated this up is beyond me. Thanks.

Comment: Google's strategy of calling everybody else "less secure" for no reason other than promoting their own privative software.

Comment: Note that you cannot avail yourself of this solution if your account has two-factor authentication enabled.  D'oh!

Comment: XMPP works in Pidgin with Google for me.

Comment: Doesn't work since Google has disabled Less Secure Apps.

Answer (score 19):

I used:

in the Basic Tab:

```
Protocol: XMPP
Username: myusername (without @mydomain.com)
Domain: mydomain.com
Resource: (left this blank as default)
Password: mypassword
Checked Remember password
```

in the Advanced Tab:

```
Connection security: Require encryption
Connect port: 5222 (default)
Connect server: talk.google.com
```

If your account uses Two-Factor Authentication, generate an [app password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) and use it as the password.

Comment: Just to surface [Nathan Adams'](http://superuser.com/questions/324863/how-do-i-set-up-google-talk-in-pidgin#comment611753_324938) comment - if you're using a custom Google Apps domain, make sure you fill in the `Connect server`; the connection dropdown won't do it.

Comment: Doesn't work since Google has disabled XMPP support.

Answer (score 4):

I had to use Pidgin version 2.10.9, with the following settings:

```
Protocol: XMPP
Username: <Gmail user name> (without @gmail.com)
Domain: gmail.com
Resource: <blank>
Password: <app-specific password>
Remember password: Checked
```

In the Advanced Tab:

```
Connection security: Use Old-style SSL
Connect port: 443
Connect server: talk.google.com
File transfer proxies: proxy.eu.jabber.org (the default)
```

I'm not sure why I needed a different port than the other answers. Because I use two-factor authentification, or am behind a corporate firewall?

Comment: Doesn't work since Google has disabled XMPP support.

Answer (score 3):

1. Create an [app-specific password](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords) for pidgin
2. Add a pidgin account

   - Protocol: XMPP
   - Username: (your google username)
   - Domain: gmail.com
   - Password: (your app-specific password)
3. That's it! There is no step 3!

Comment: Doesn't work since Google has disabled XMPP support.

Answer (score 2):

Pidgin comes preconfigured with an option in the drop-down menu called "Google Talk", which has all the settings already done. Type in your username/password and you should be able to connect.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't help.  It also changed back to XMPP.

Comment: Are you behind a network proxy? If so, please fill in those details and try the "google talk" protocol method again.

Comment: If I remember correctly - if you select google talk in the drop down it won't allow you to use an account you have setup for your own domain because it changes to XMPP. I believe for that you have to manually configure it per yuvilo's instructions.

Comment: Doesn't work since Google has disabled XMPP support.

Answer (score 1):

Update:

> Doesn't work since Google has disabled XMPP support.

---

Gtalk is not working now, so I'm using pidgin now, and it's working great

Setting I've used:

in the Basic Tab:

```
Protocol: XMPP
Username: yourUsername (without @mydomain.com)
Domain: mydomain.com
Resource: (left this blank as default)
Password: yourPassword
Checked Remember password
```

in the Advanced Tab:

```
Connection security: Use Old-style SSL
Connect port: 5223 (there would be 5222 change it)
Connect server: talk.google.com
```

Comment: Doesn't work since Google has disabled XMPP support.

Answer (score 0):

You want to include your full domain in the username field, for example `john.doe@gmail.com` (which is needed for Google Apps accounts). You can leave the "domain" field blank.

[image]

Comment: When I try that, I get:  `Invalid XMPP ID`

Comment: Pidgin requires you to type them apart; so, typing them together won't work.

Comment: Doesn't work since Google has disabled XMPP support.

Answer (score 0):

Just leave the File transfer proxies as blank in the Advanced tab.

Comment: Source? That doesn't seem right

Answer (score 0):

for me this helped:

```
Connection security: Use encryption if available.
Connect port: 5222
Connect server: talk.google.com
Also in Resource I entered "Home"
```

Comment: Doesn't work since Google has disabled XMPP support.

Answer (score 0):

I tried every method, same issue. The below settings fixed it:

Basic Tab:
Protocol: XMPP
Username: username (without the @gmail.com)
Resource: Empty
Password: Yourpassword

Advanced Tab:
Connection security: Use encryption if available
Connect server: talk.google.com
File transfer proxies: empty (delete whats here)

Save, click enable check box.

Comment: Doesn't work since Google has disabled XMPP support.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set app-specific password for Pidgin. Just follow the instructions at [this link](http://mylinuxbook.com/how-to-get-pidgin-working-with-gtalk/).

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.