# How can I connect Pidgin to Google Hangouts?

Tags: pidgin, xmpp, jabber, google-hangouts

I've followed several Howto's with no success. Do I need a special type of account perhaps? I did turn on access for less secure apps. Is there a waiting period for Hangouts after creating a new Google account?

I don't use Google Apps but there seems to be some suggestion that I need something pertaining to G Apps.

Errors:

```
10:15:52) skype: Sending: 'SEARCH MISSEDCHATMESSAGES'
(10:15:59) proxy: Connecting to google.com:5222.
(10:15:59) proxy: Error connecting to google.com:5222 (Connection timed out).
(10:15:59) proxy: Connection attempt failed: Connection timed out
(10:15:59) proxy: Attempting connection to 64.233.177.100
(10:15:59) proxy: Connecting to google.com:5222 with no proxy
(10:15:59) proxy: Connection in progress
```

Note that I've also tried "gmail" instead of "google". I'm using 2.10.12

Comment: Which howtos have you tried? What happened?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set up Google Talk/Hangout in Pidgin?](https://superuser.com/questions/973514/how-do-i-set-up-google-talk-hangout-in-pidgin)

Answer (score 5):

You need to enter `talk.google.com` to "Connect Server" in "Advanced" tab. Below is the example for gokcer@gmail.com

Account information:

[image: Account information]

Server information:

[image: Server information]

Comment: I am quite sure you can leave the "server" address blank (talk.google.com), usually I just leaved it blank because it is automatically associated to the domain `gmail.com`. Another answer here is addressing this.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've got the "connect server" (in the Advanced tab) filled in wrong.  Try unsetting that and just leaving it blank, with your "domain" field filled in with "gmail.com", eg:
[image: BasicTab][image: Advanced tab]

(On a side note, it also looks like you're using the old and outdated skype plugin.  Try the newer [skypeweb plugin](https://github.com/EionRobb/skype4pidgin/tree/master/skypeweb#skypeweb-plugin-for-pidgin) instead)